# Loop through table and parse multiple arguments to scripts in Bash

Tags: bash, loops, csv, arguments

I am in a situation similar to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103932/parsing-a-delimited-text-file-in-bash-as-command-arguments) and having difficulties implementing this kind of solution for my situation.

I have `file.tsv` formatted as follows:

```
x     y
dog     woof
CAT     meow
loud_goose     honk-honk
duck     quack
```

with a fixed number of columns (but variable rows) and I need to loop those pairs of values, all but the first one, in a script like the following (pseudocode)

```
for elements in list; do
    ./script1 elements[1] elements[2]
    ./script2 elements[1] elements[2]
done
```

so that `script*` can take the arguments from the pair and run with it.

Is there a way to do it in Bash?

I was thinking I could do something like this:

```
list1={`awk 'NR > 1{print $1}' file.tsv`}
list2={`awk 'NR > 1{print $2}' file.tsv`}
```

and then to call them in the loop based on their position, but I am not sure on how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try just a `while` + `read` loop with the `-a` flag and IFS.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS=$' \t' read -ra line; do
  echo ./script1 "${line[0]}" "${line[1]}"
  echo ./script2 "${line[0]}" "${line[1]}"
done < <(tail -n +2 file.tsv)
```

---

Or without the `tail`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

skip=0 start=-1

while IFS=$' \t' read -ra line; do
  if ((start++ >= skip)); then
    echo ./script1 "${line[0]}" "${line[1]}"
    echo ./script2 "${line[0]}" "${line[1]}"
  fi
done < file.tsv
```

---

- Remove the `echo`'s if you're satisfied with the output.

Answer (score 2):

Shell tables are not multi-dimensional so table element cannot store two arguments for your scripts. However since you are processing lines from `file.tsv`, you can iterate on each line, reading both elements at once like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Populate tab with a tab character
tab="$(printf '\t')"

# Since printf's sub-shell added a trailing newline, remove it
tab="${tab%?}"

{
  # Read first line in dummy variable _ to skip header
  read -r _

  # Iterate reading tab delimited x and y from each line
  while IFS="$tab" read -r x y || [ -n "$x" ]; do
    ./script1 "$x" "$y"
    ./script2 "$x" "$y"
  done
} < file.tsv # from this file
```

Comment: I think that should do, thanks, I will test it now. Do you mind if I ask what `|| [ -n "$x" ]` does in the condition?

Comment: In case the last line of the file does not end with a newline character, the `read` command will return failure while still reading the x and y fields. `|| [ -n "$x" ]` tests that variable x is not empty (has been read). → read x y successfully or check x is not empty